# objectify load @subclass by id

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I have those classes:

```
@Entity(name = "Post")
public abstract class PostRecord {

    @Id
    private Long id;
}


@Subclass(name = "Bulletin", index = true)
public class BulletinRecord extends PostRecord {

}
```

I am trying to fetch the bulletinRecord by id, but i always get null.
Here is my attempts:

```
ofy().load().type(BulletinRecord.class).id(bulletinId).now();
ofy().load().type(PostRecord.class).id(bulletinId).now();
ofy().load().key(Key.create(Key.create(PostRecord.class , bulletinId), BulletinRecord.class, bulletinId)).now();
ofy().load().type(BulletinRecord.class).filter("id=", postId).first().now();
ofy().load().type(PostRecord.class).filter("id=", postId).first().now();
```

and i can see my record at developer console with the id that i am trying to fetch:
[image: bulletin record in datstore]

someone could tell me what i am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is. If your classes are exactly as you describe them, the first two lines should work. The third line won't work because you're trying to use a `@Parent` key. The last two won't work because you can't filter by `@Id` fields (they aren't indexed properties, they're part of the key).

Comment: Sorry for coming to late. I have others entities without subclasses and i can fetch them by id, how is the first and second lines. The only case i cant get by id is with a subclass. These entity PostRecord has 3 subclasses, BulletinRecord, SessionRecord and NewsRecord. I can list all Bulletins, all sessions, all news or all posts. It works fine when i try to list, but when i try to fetch by id, i get null. I already check the id and it is the right id.

Comment: Thanks to @stickfigure , i solve my problem. The post record class, has others fields and i dont put them here becouse i think them was not important to my issue. I was wrong. The post has a **@Parent** field and after see your comment i tried this code `ofy().load().key(Key.create(Key.create(UserRecord.class , userId), BulletinRecord.class, bulletinId)).now();`
and it works very well.